# Is there a way to be notified of changes (like new file uploaded) in a Google Drive service account?

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

I am using C# Google Drive API to upload and download some files. My credential is of a Service Account type. I am uploading files to the Drive from a separate Docker container. My C# application(.NET Framework) needs to know when this happens without constantly checking the Drive folder. How can I do this without having an exposed Endpoint or URI ? Also is having a URI with IP address/dedicated domain name absolutely necessary?

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating a watch requests for your resources so that your c# application won't need to check your drive from time to time. You can check this [reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/push) guide to create watch requests depending on the associated watch method for the resource.